# Extending documentation for object

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc, cypress

I am writing some Cypress and javascript for some testing and I have an Object `cy`.
This object is documented and I get some intellisense for it, however I want to extend it with some of my own properties, and I am wondering if I can extend the documentation as well.

The code I have is kind of like this

```
cy.bo = {
    header: {
        get: () => header()
    }
}
```

Which kind of works. I can access `cy.bo.header.get` from my tests and everything works, but my IDE(vscode) will of course say that `cy.bo` is of type `any`.

So the question I have is: can I extend the documentation of this object to also cover my own hacked in properties?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just add your [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) as you would normally for the extra members that you add to the object literal.

See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: for whatever reason that doesn't work. Could it be because of some odd tsconfig on my side?

Comment: Ah! Your question was tagged JavaScript, so I did not try with TypeScript. VSCode is not providing auto-completion documentation with the JSDoc. *BUT* if you want to be correct and your documentation to also be correct, perhaps it is better to leverage the type system instead of relying on some sort of documentation.

Comment: So this is where my lack of knowledge shines through :) I am typing in `.js` files so it is javascript. But I have a tsconfig per instruction on cypress and in that I have `"allowJs": true`

Comment: "tsconfig" will not affect the way VSCode provides auto-completion and documentation. Maybe update your version of the software? My screenshot was taken from a vanilla installation without any added extension. If I type correct code in VSCode (for both JavaScript and TypeScript), I am getting proper IntelliSense. This makes me think that the rest your code might be incorrect somehow.